# Execution failed for task ':react-native-admob:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, admob

I had a third-party dependency (react-native-admob) which specified in its build.gradle file the following: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+. Taking a look over at the Google Android APIs release notes page, there were breaking updates to the whole com.google.android.gms group of APIs on 17th June 2019.

I run './gradlew assembleDebug' got error:

> /Users/yons/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/8cb1ac92f08bb5fb26b003aaf1d22a69/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> /Users/yons/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/8cb1ac92f08bb5fb26b003aaf1d22a69/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

To fix my issue, I added the following to my android/app/build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
}
```

Now, I run './gradlew assembleDebug' works fine. 
But I run './gradlew assembleRelease' got an error:

> /Users/yons/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/8cb1ac92f08bb5fb26b003aaf1d22a69/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> /Users/yons/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/8cb1ac92f08bb5fb26b003aaf1d22a69/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> error: failed linking references.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':react-native-admob:verifyReleaseResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is related migration to Androidx, google play service updated to androidX 
 This problem belongs to `react-native-device-info`? best option is to upgrade `react-native-device-info` using

1. yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@2.1.2
2. cd android && gradlew clean
3. react-native run-android

After which you either change it like explained in the answer above. like so

```
implementation(project(":react-native-admob"),  {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
})
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes, The root cause is related migration to Androidx. I had try modify android/app/build.gradle file
'''
implementation(project(":react-native-admob"),  {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
})
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"
'''
I run './gradlew assembleDebug' works fine, but run './gradlew assembleRelease' got an error

Comment: @罗国辉 Did you run 'gradlew clean'?

Comment: I did not use react-native-device-info, I use react-native-admob this lib depend com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads

Comment: So, would you like to update 'react-native-admob' to the latest version? 'Yarn upgrade real-native-admob@lastest'

Comment: ***and***  `./gradlew app:dependencies > deps.txt`  ***and*** add this to local.properties: `firebaseVersion=17.6.0
googlePlayServicesVersion=16.1.0
googlePlayServicesVisionVersion=16.2.0`